# add_theme_support post-thumbnails not working

Tags: post-thumbnails

I tried to add thumbnail support to my theme

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', 
     array( 'post', 'page', 'service', '100', '90') 
);
```

Comment: what are 100 and 90? Which hook is used to call this code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [**documentation**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#post-thumbnails).

> **This feature must be called** before the `init` hook is fired. That means it needs to be placed directly into `functions.php` or within a function attached to the `after_setup_theme` hook. For custom post types, you can also add post thumbnails using the `register_post_type()` function as well.

TRY this

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', 
     array( 'post', 'page', 'service') 
);
```